# Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cell if it Contains Specific Text in 2 Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to highlight a cell using conditional formatting based on matching criteria in 2 different cells, 1 of which is the cell I want highlighted. In a row if a cell contains "ABC" and "Yes" in another I want the Yes cell highlighted.

I've yet to be able to figure out how to get this to work after searching and searching formulas. I've tried different IF, AND, etc formulas to no avail.

Comment: Can you give us specific cell addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the conditional format to the cell that you want to be formatted. Use a conditional format with a formula. If you want to evaluate two different cells, you can use the AND() function to combine conditions, for example select cell B and use this CF formula

```
=AND(A1="ABC",B1="Yes")
```

This formula will evaluate to either TRUE or FALSE and the conditional format will be applied when the result is TRUE.

If you want the whole row to change color, select all the cells in row 1 and make sure that the formula locks in the correct columns with the $ sign.

```
=AND($A1="ABC",$B1="Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

In cell `A1`, I've put `ABC`, and in `B1`, I've put `Yes`.

Then I used following formula in another cell's conditinal formatting:

```
=AND(EXACT(A1;"ABC");EXACT(B1;"Yes"))
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use the `=` operator? Unless you need case sensitive comparison, of course, but that was not in the question.

Comment: @teylyn: indeed, it's simplier, but I prefer to avoid it: in programming languages, the `=` sign is used to assign a value to a variable, while `==` is used as a comparison operator. So using `=` as a comparison operator can be confusing for someone, used to programming.

Comment: @Dominique, except in `VBA` where `=` is used to both assign value and test comparison! ;)

Comment: Seems to me that the formula approach leads to more problems that the operator approach, considering function names vary per lanugage.